# get the return value of the method which is from Generic class in java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I created a parent class Repo which has methods for insert, delete, display and delete objects in a list. Repo is a generic class. I created a child classes for Repo (like DepartmentRepo class)and pass Department, Employee, etc.. classes.  I want perform insert, delete, display and delete operations on any class objects that passed to Repo class.
I need to get the return value of the method "get" which is from Generic class in java. I can only get the method name from Generic  here I mention the code files

```
public class Department {
    private long Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Location;
    
    public Department() {
        
    }
    
    public Department(long id, String name, String location) {
        super();
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Location = location;
    }
    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return Location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        Location = location;
    }
    
    

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Repo<T, U> {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    public List<T> getAll() {
        return list;
    }

    public void insert(T obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public T get(U id) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        for (T ele : list) {
            if (ele.getClass().getMethod("getId") == id) {
                return ele;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void delete(U id) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        list.remove(get(id));
    }
}
```

```
public class DepartmentRepo extends Repo<Department, Long>{

}
```

```
class MainApi
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        DepartmentRepo dept = new DepartmentRepo ();
        Department ict=new Department(10001,"Dept of ICT","Town");
        Department cs=new Department(10002,"Dept of Computer Science","Pampaimadu");
        Department bio=new Department(10003,"Dept of Bio Science","Pampaimadu");
        Department sats=new Department(10004,"Dept of Statistics","Kurumankadu");
        
        dept.insert(ict);
        dept.insert(cs);
        dept.insert(bio);
        dept.insert(sats);
        System.out.println();
        dept.getAll();
        try{
            dept.get(10001);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not even using your Repo class, what is the problem? the Department class doesn't have the get method you call

Comment: Repo class used by DepartmentRepo. do you know basic inheritance and generics ?

Comment: Missed that class. Actually, all you need to do, is create an instance with those types, there's no need to create an (empty) class for it. You're aware you are hiding any errors you might encounter?

Comment: There are no errors in my code. DepartmentRepo is not an empty class. if I want, I can add some specific methods that related to department.

Comment: in the code you've shown, you are hiding exceptions. In the code you've shown, DepartmentRepo is empty. Remember, we can just go on the code you show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As another solution, and an answer to your comment, you could use elements inheritance, and avoid reflection calls and exceptions.

1- Create an element interface OR class

```java
public interface RepoElement<U> {
    U getId();
}
```

OR

```java
public class RepoElement<U> {
    private U Id;

    public RepoElement() {}

    public RepoElement(U id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public U getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(U id) {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

2- Make `Department` inherit from the interface OR class

```java
public class Department implements RepoElement<Long> {
    (...)
    public Long getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    (...)
}
```

OR

```java
public class Department extends RepoElement<Long> {
    private String Name;
    private String Location;

    public Department() {
        super();
    }

    public Department(long id, String name, String location) {
        super(id);
        Name = name;
        Location = location;
    }

}
```

3- Use it directly in the `Repo` class (and remove exceptions)

```java
public class Repo<T extends RepoElement<U>, U> {
    (...)
    public T get(U id) {
        for (T ele : list) {
            if (ele.getId().equals(id)) {
                return ele;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void delete(U id) {
        list.remove(get(id));
    }
    (...)
}
```

As a last suggestion, you could use a `Map` instead of a `List` in the `Repo` class, and get rid of any search complexity/optimizations:

```java
public class Repo<T extends RepoElement<U>, U> {
    Map<U, T> map = new HashMap<U, T>();

    public Collection<T> getAll() {
        return map.values();
    }

    public void insert(T obj) {
        map.put(obj.getId(), obj);
    }

    public T get(U id) {
        return map.get(id);
    }

    public void delete(U id) {
        map.remove(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working as standalone Java classes. but when I try to implement with REST API(Jersy), getId() return nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the getId() method so that it will return the id to perform comparison correctly:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Repo<T, U> {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    public List<T> getAll() {
        return list;
    }

    public void insert(T obj) {
        list.add(obj);
    }

    public T get(U id) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        for (T ele : list) {
            if (ele.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(ele).equals(id)) {
                return ele;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void delete(U id) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        list.remove(get(id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. is there any better way to do this concept ?